# Weird Route Value in Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my asp.net mvc 3 site my actual route looks like `/FF.mvc/116/MVt?m=01-12-2012` but some of my users are getting error and they have weird route like

```
/FF.mvc/116/ossw=((qncufuh)niah(`r)mt
```

any idea where from this

```
ossw=((qncufuh)niah(`r)mt
```

coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch is that your applications pages are indexed by the search (google) engine (perhaps against your wishes `:)`). If you search anything for example your apps name in google you will see a similar `ossw=((qncufuh)niah(`r)mt` string in the address bar when the results are returned.

[image]

Some employee has searched the page link in google and tried to access it from there.

Inorder to prevent the search spiders from indexing your application's pages add a `robots.txt` file in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
Url = "/FF.mvc/116/MVt?m=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("01-12-2012")
```

I don't know if the char '-' will be error. 
the ((qncufuh).... might come from some strange language code.

Comment: This code is working correctly on many clients the problem is arising on one or two user